# How am I getting a "Permission denied" error in TeXworks?

Tags: miktex, tex

I compiled a .tex file in TeXworks for Windows 7 that had a graph in it, so I had to install the TikZ library for LateX.

Afterwards, all compilations are failing. The TeXworks console displays

```
texify.exe: Permission denied: myFile.log
texify.exe: Data: myFile.log
```

Strangely, I do not have the pdf document open in other programs such as Adobe Acrobat. I tried closing and reopening TeXworks to no avail.

How can I grant TeXworks permission to compile my .tex file?

Comment: sounds a bit like a problem with your admin account, maybe those logfiles were created when UAC made you admin in the installation process and you ran tex as admin afterwards? have you tried removing them?

Answer (score 3):

Start Explorer,
go to directory with that file and delete the log file. After that try
again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I tried terminating the processes "winedit" and "pdflatex" from the Task Manager and restarted winedit. Compiled the .tex file again. It worked. 
I think this error occurs because the pdflatex process is still running so new instance cannot run during that.
Just terminating "pdflatex" process will also work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting the same message, maybe with other (built) files (.aux, .pdf, etc), check if you didn't accidentally drag & drop a file into the editor. Turns out I did, and TexMaker added a `\includegraphics[scale=1]{build/document.pdf}` line in the middle of the document. The file was being made and requested to read the same time, and this caused the error.

(Sorry if it's spam, but maybe helps someone hopelessly searching for the error.)